# How to mirror traffic and remove duplicate at destination

Tags: ubuntu, ip, mirroring, policy-routing, duplicate-ip

I would like to send same trafic over two vpns (udp), to the same server (ubuntu 22.04 with two different WAN interfaces).

```
                              /-WAN1-> VPN1 client-\
App-server <-> VPNs server<--/                      \--> App-client
                             \ -WAN2-> VPN2 client- /
```

Trafic direction flow that need to be duplicated is : app-client to app-server.
No need to duplicate traffic from app-server to app-client.
Is there a way I can generate/send duplicate traffic, and remove duplicate at destination ?

client and server machines are ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: This is a canonical example of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov "If someone asks for more information, do provide details.". you can ask for more information, if you think that there are missing information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible, on the source make two vpn interfaces, and two vpns, and use a tool like iptables to duplicate the traffic, and configure proper routing.
On the app server you need to configure to accept traffic from both vpns. Using firewall rules for example. To remove duplicates is very challenging but that can also be done with firewall rules.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes i have read i can duplicate the packet using iptables and tee option. But can you please explain how to remove duplicates ?

Comment: Removing duplicates from network traffic at the destination (App-server) typically involves tracking and filtering out redundant packets. To do this, you can implement deduplication logic in your application or at the network level.

Comment: if you're working with iptables on Ubuntu, you might create a custom rule using the --conntrack module to track connections and drop packets that match the same connection. This approach may look like:`iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -m recent --update --seconds 60 -j DROP`. Here, this rule drops incoming packets if they belong to a connection that was seen within the last 60 seconds. This way, if a duplicate packet arrives within a short time frame, it would be dropped.